# How to delete multiple columns in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Is that possible to delete multiple columns by reference using data.table?

None of the following works

```
library(data.table);
dt <- mtcars %>% setDT

# THESE ARE NOT RUNNABLE
dt[, range := NULL, with = F]
dt[, (range) := NULL, with = F]
dt[, ..range:=NULL]
dt[, ':='(.SD=NULL), .SDcols=range] 
dt[, lapply(.SD, NULL), .SDcols=range] 
dt[, ':='(mget(range)):=NULL]
```

Can you help?

PS. Eventually, for each of the lines above to I would like to know when it can or when it cannot be used (evidently, they can't be used for deleting a range of columns, but they can be used for selecting , or assigning values to, a range of columns)

Comment: What is `range`.  Perhaps `range <- c("mpg", "cyl");
> dt[, (range) := NULL]; names(dt)
[1] "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(mtcars)

dt[, `:=`(wt=NULL, hp=NULL, disp=NULL, am=NULL, gear=NULL, carb=NULL)]
```

Output:

```
> head(dt)
    mpg cyl drat  qsec vs
1: 21.0   6 3.90 16.46  0
2: 21.0   6 3.90 17.02  0
3: 22.8   4 3.85 18.61  1
4: 21.4   6 3.08 19.44  1
5: 18.7   8 3.15 17.02  0
6: 18.1   6 2.76 20.22  1
```

Or as akrun wrote:

```
range = c("wt", "hp", "disp", "am", "gear", "carb")
dt[, (range):=NULL]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `range` is something like 1:3 then you could do...

```
range<-1:3

DT1[,(names(DT1)[range]):=NULL]
```

or

```
set(DT1, j=range, value=NULL)
```